# Ajax links inside ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

i am having trouble getting ajax loaded links to load other ajax content.
Basically this is my ajax code:

```
$(function () {

var api = $("#content").jScrollPane().data('jsp');

    var reinitialiseScrollPane = function()
    {
        api.reinitialise();
    }

// attaching click handler to links
$("#contentcontainer a[href]").click(function (e) {
    // cancel the default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the address of the link
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // getting the desired element for working with it later
    var $wrap = $('#content');
    $wrap
        // removing old data
        api.getContentPane()

        // load the remote page
        .load(href, reinitialiseScrollPane , function (){

        }
    );
});

});
```

Basically the links inside the navigation work fine since they are loaded when page is loaded, but links inside the ajax content (wich are supposed to load pages in the same place the navigation links load content) dont work, my understanding is that there needs some sort of ".live" function called as the js does not rescan the code once ajax loads content.

I found some solutions but none i could relate to the code im using.
The first part of the code is not ajax but for a scrollbar plugin, i did not remove it because id like to avoid it getting voided by a solution that dosent keep it into count.

Thanks.

Comment: What is this? `$("#contentcontainer a[href]").click`. Remove [href] part and check again.

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov It's perfectly legit and valid. It means that the click event is only bound to `<a>` elements that has a `href` attribute specified.

Comment: Ok, just never use it :) Try to use live binding via `$.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov It works, but exactly like my code. If i click on a link loaded by ajax, it will send me to the page instead of loading it in #content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `.on()` method (see [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)) when attaching the click handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#contentcontainer a[href]', function (e) {
    // Rest of your code here
});
```

Comment: It works, but exactly like my code. If i click on a link loaded by ajax, it will send me to the page instead of loading it in #content.

Comment: `$wrap
        // removing old data
        api.getContentPane()` how does this work i don't see any open braces

Comment: Check your console log for errors, as pointed out by @AlexV.Kostyukov

Comment: @AlexV.Kostyukov sorry "// removing old data api.getContentPane()" is also from jscrollpane, it reads the new content and decides if it should place a scrollbar in it, the removing old data comment is wrong.

I get no errors in my console.

Comment: You have an unclosed curly bracket. See the line where `$wrap` is at - it is syntactically wrong.

Comment: FezMonki do you check missing brace after $wrap?